# jquery form submit not working

Tags: jquery

in some reason if I use this code it sends the form in normal way not with jquery? What could be the problem? thanks

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#formi").submit(function() {
        $(":text, textarea").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === "") {
                $('p#error').fadeIn(1000);
                var tyhjia = true;
            }
        });
        if (tyhjia == true) {
            // tyhjia on , joten ei jatketa
        } else {
            // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
            var fname = $('#name').attr('value');
            var lname = $('#email').attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "laheta-viesti",
                data: "name=" + fname + "& email=" + lname,
                success: function() {
                    $('form#formi').hide();
                    $('p#valmista').fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is very bad at indents, dont care them since they seems not to display correctly here

Comment: By `very bad at indents`, do you mean the system failed to sanitize the poorly-indented code *you* submitted?

Comment: the code is not poorly indented.How should I indent it -what you say?

Comment: @Olli, highlight your code and click on the Code Sample button (`{ }`). It will automatically append 4 whitespaces in front of each line which will be enough to show the code properly.

Comment: oh, i didnt know that. i think its very handy feature. Why is it documented nowhere?

Comment: @Olli, it is documented => there is a `?` orange button where you could get advanced help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Errors in your javascript are the common cause for this behavior. For example you have defined the `tyhjia` variable inside the anonymous callback and try to use it outside. I have tried to clean your code a little:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form#formi').submit(function() {
            var tyhjia = false;
            $(':text, textarea').each(function() {
                if($(this).val() === '') {
                    $('p#error').fadeIn(1000);
                    tyhjia = true;
                }
            });

            if (tyhjia == true) {
                // tyhjia on , joten ei jatketa
            } else {
                // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
                var fname = $('#name').val();
                var lname = $('#email').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'laheta-viesti',
                    data: { name: fname, email: lname },
                    success: function() {
                        $('form#formi').hide();
                        $('p#valmista').fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Of course there could be some other errors left. Use FireBug or Chrome Developer Tool and inspect the console for any possible errors reported.

And by the way for doing validation, which is what apparently you are trying to do here, I would very strongly recommend you the [jquery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Comment: now I have a new problem. When I have other forms in the page it also affects them. So how I could change it to only affect the "formi" form. I tried this `$("#formi:text, #formi:textarea").each(function() {` but it didnt work. Hopefully you or someone else could help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the jquery behavior to replace the default behavior completely, you must explicitly tell it to not do the default behavior like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("form#formi").submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
```

notice that two lines of code changed - you must get "e" which is a common abbreviation for "event" from the function as a parameter, then tell it not to perform the default behavior.

Comment: He already returns false at the end of the submit callback, which is the same.